# Google Chrome computed value weirdness

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

According to the specification `vertical-align` property in percentage is relative to `line-height` property of the element itself. So I made a test and in Chrome Dev Tools the computed value is not present in pixels like in Firefox and IE11. This behavior is weird and I wonder is this a bug or ? I know that all other values in Chrome are computed to pixels and it's odd that `vertical-align` is not computed to pixels.

Here is the test http://jsfiddle.net/blaja/r5m2yc7e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [propdef for `vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) indeed says that values specified as percentages must be computed to an absolute length based on the line height, i.e. a pixel value. Depending on whether the browser definition of "computed value" is supposed to be consistent with the [CSS definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#computed-value), this may or may not be a bug *per se*.

For that matter, all three browsers appear to be incorrectly computing `line-height` to an absolute value as well. The spec says if the specified value is a number, not a length, then [the computed value is the same as the specified value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height); it should not resolve to an absolute length unless it is specified as such (or as a percentage). In your case, `line-height` is specified on the `p` element as `1.5`. This same value should be inherited by the `span`, *then* used in calculating the exact line height needed to render the line box(es). The resultant line height is the [*used value*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#used-value), not the *computed value*.

Comment: Note that the resolved value of line-height (the value returned by `getComputedStyle()`) is the used value, not the computed value. It could by that the value shown by the browser dev tools is trying to be consistent with that. Chrome's vertical-align computed value definitely looks like a bug though.

Comment: I sent a question to Tab Atkins(spec writer) about this and waiting for answer, but definitely something weird is happening here. Why chrome is not aligned with IE and FF about vertical-align property I don't know but I assume it is a bug or maybe not!?
I made one more demo and it confirms all what I said.
http://jsfiddle.net/blaja/dzp7Lcfv/2/

Comment: I just received an email from Tab, and he says that this looks like a bug. I just reported it.

Comment: Here is the report https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403796 in case you are interested.